# How could change the matrix terms to zero matrix in a loop?

Tags: programming

Dear Mathematica experts;

I have a code such as;

```
For[e=1,e<3,e++,
Be=ConstantArray[0,{3,3}];
a=1;
For[i=1,i<4,i++,
Be[[1,i]]=dRdx[[1,a,e]];
a=a+1;
];
];
```

When $e=1$, I get right solutions which are assigned to matrix `Be` but for $e=2$; I get wrong results?

What is the reason for this problem?

Comment: What would be the correct results you would like for `e == 2`? More generally, could you describe what you are trying to do? There almost certainly a better approach than a `For` loop.